# Show inherited methods etc in Visual Paradigm

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

I'm using Visual Paradigm CE for some UML-Design.

Is there any way to display all inherited methods in a class diagramm?
Can't figure out where to find it in the options, am I just blind or is there no way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do that and for a reason. If in UML you write the method in both classes (parent and child) then this means that the method is overriden in the child class. I'll illustrate:

```
+--------+         +--------+
| Class1 |         | Class2 |
+--------+<|-------+--------+
| m1()   |         |        |
+--------+         +--------+
```

Here when you execute `class2.m1()` the method `class1.m1()` will be executed (`class1` and `class2` are instances of `Class1` and `Class2` respectively). If you model like this:

```
+--------+         +--------+
| Class1 |         | Class2 |
+--------+<|-------+--------+
| m1()   |         | m1()   |
+--------+         +--------+
```

It means that `Class2` has a **new** implementation of `m1()` and that implementation will be called.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: This is clearly not the right answer. Note Chaz answer below.

Answer (score 8):

- Right Click Class > Presentation Options > Attributes > Show Inherited
  Attributes
- Right Click Class > Presentation Options > Operations > Show
  Inherited Operations

I'm actually using Agilian (also VP Suite) but I assume it's identical.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is more likely related to the option "show-hide" inheritance links between classifiers inside a class diagram.
This option is available in very few tools. I know RSA and Omondo have it.

This is a kind of live navigation in the model which is more related to the Omondo EclipseUML metamodeling approach.